# How to pass an extra parameter

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parameter-passing, uigesturerecognizer

I need to pass an second parameter with the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer's` `selector`

```
 let lpGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didLongPressCell))
```

I need to send the cell that was long pressed also. Is there any way to do that

Thanks in advance

Comment: UILongPressGestureRecognizer has a property "view", which will show you the view that the gesture is attached to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function has two parameters like below.

```
func clicked(sender:AnyObject,value:AnyObject)
{
}
```

Then

```
action = "clicked::"
```

example :

```
func switchCard(card: Int, withCard card1: Int) 
{
    print(card)
}

let singleTap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "switchCard:withCard:")
```

Just a note on Swift 2.2. You can now type the selector as

```
#selector(popoverSelectedCode(_:desc:)
```

Answer (score 1):

First change your `selector` syntax of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` like this

```
#selector(self.didLongPressCell(_:))
```

Now add this `didLongPressCell` method in your `viewController`

```
func didLongPressCell(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if (gesture.state == .Ended) {
         let point = gesture.locationInView(self.tableView)
         let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
         let customCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomCell
         //This is the cell that you want.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use gesture `.view` property to get long pressed view.

Try to do as follows:

```
func didLongPressCell(gesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
  let cell: UITableViewCell = gesture.view as! UITableViewCell
  print(cell.textLabel?.text)
  //use this cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you want to send the view to the action function and that the gesture is added to that view.

In this case you can just get the `view` From the gesture that's passed to the action function.

It looks like your action function currently doesn't take any parameters based on the selector you're using so you need to correct that too.

Answer (score 0):

You need add

> (_:)

in `#selector(didLongPressCell(_:))` and you method will look like

```
let lpGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didLongPressCell(_:)))

func didLongPressCell(sender: UIView!) -> Void {
      //Your sender here is a cell
}
```